# dynamic url to static url rewrite and redirection

Tags: .htaccess, url, redirect, mod-rewrite

I have a dynamic website based on php.
So I just want to know how can I automatically redirect this url

```
/convert.php?id=any-id&v=any-string [L]
```

to

```
/tutorial/any-string/any-id.html
```

I have created the following htaccess code

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteOptions inherit
RewriteRule ^videos/([^/]*)\.html$ /search.php?s=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^tutorial/([^/]*)/([^/]*)\.html$ /convert.php?id=$1&v=$2 [L]
```

I  am capable to get that static url but what I want is if someone enters the dynamic url in the browser he/she should get redirected automatically new static url.

Any suggestion ?

Answer (score 0):

Change your .htaccess file to reflect the following rules and it will work as you want.

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteOptions inherit
RewriteRule ^videos/([^/]*)\.html$ /search.php?s=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^tutorial/([^/]*)/([^/]*)\.html$ /convert.php?id=$1&v=$2 [L]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)id=any-id($|&)
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)v=any-string($|&)
RewriteRule ^convert\.php$ /tutorial/any-string/any-id.html? [L,R=301]
```

Comment: In that URL, any-string & any-id will be dynamic value which will get changed automatically, do you think it's written in a right way ? @error2007s

Answer (score 0):

Add another rewrite rule to handle dynamic URL in the end:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteOptions inherit

RewriteRule ^videos/([\w-]+)\.html$ search.php?s=$1 [L,QSA,NC]

RewriteRule ^tutorial/([^/]+)/([\w-]+)\.html$ convert.php?id=$1&v=$2 [L,QSA,NC]

RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)\.html$ convert.php?id=$1&v=$2 [L,QSA,NC]
```